# Supervisor service doesn't have access to audio device ("Error while setting open_pcm: No such file or directory")

Tags: python, systemd, supervisord, alsa, liquidsoap

I'm using Supervisor to demonize a Python / Liquidsoap application. When I start the application from the command line, things are working fine.

When I run the same application using `supervisorctl` the Liquidsoap implementation fails when trying to access the audio device:

```
[lineout:3] Using ALSA 1.1.8.
[clock.wallclock_alsa:2] Error when starting output lineout: Failure("Error while setting open_pcm: No such file or directory")!
```

The USB Audio Interface is accessed via ALSA. The Supervisor Configuration has the correct user set and the service is started with this very user:

```
[program:aura-engine]
user = engineuser
directory = /opt/aura/engine
command = /opt/aura/engine/run.sh engine

priority = 666
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stopsignal = TERM

redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/aura/engine-core-stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/aura/engine-core-error.log
```

Any ideas if there are any additional hardware permission issues involved when using Supervisord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, that starting the application with `root` (root user in Supervisor config, but also starting `supervisord` as root, plus starting the service with `sudo supervisorctl start...`) successfully grants access to the audio hardware. But running the app as `root` is not an option. This also issues a warning by Supervisor.

Then I returned the configuration to the desired `engineuser`, and did reload the configuration with sudo:

```
sudo supervisorctl reload
```

Now, suddenly I'm able to start the app without root/sudo and have full access to the audio hardware:

```
supervisorctl start aura-engine
```